# How to model the following in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using Rails 3.2.8 and mySql as the db. I have two models, Setup and Regions. I can have only N regions (N right now being 6) and there can be many setups of which each setup  has to be in one Region.

The most obvious way seems to be Setup has_one Region. However this gives every new setup a new region object. However, I wish to reuse the region object in a setup (so that when its parameters change, they change across the board for all setups) and not create a new Region for every setup I have. I am thinking the best way is the following

```
class Setup < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :region_id
end

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name
end
```

If I want the region associated with the setup in the controller I do

```
setup = Setup.find(id)
region = Region.find(setup.region_id)
```

I am just wondering aloud whether this is the way it is done or is there any other way to capture this in Rails with ActiveRecord or is there any neat abstraction around it so that i can do something like the following?

```
region = setup.region
```

Comment: use association in Setup model use `belongs_to :region` and Region model `has_many :setups` then you can do setup.region

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do things the opposite to your first inclination -- `Region has_many :setups`, and `Setup belongs_to :region` (which would require `Setup` having a `:region_id` column, as you were thinking). Then, through the magic of Rails associations, Rails will give provide a number of association methods linking the two objects, such as:

```
@setup.region # the region associated with that setup
@region.setups # all setups associated with the region
```

There are a bunch of association methods -- I'd recommend reading the [Association Basics guid](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to familiarize yourself with them, particular the references for the [`has_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference) and [`belongs_to`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference) associations.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why I blanked out there and did not see this obvious inverse relationship!

Answer (score 1):

use association in 
Setup model use 
`belongs_to :region` 
and 
Region model 
`has_many :setups`

Like below:--

```
class Setup < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  belongs_to :region
end

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :setups
end
```

Then you can do
`setup = Setup.find(id)`
`region = setup.region`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your Setup `belongs_to` a Region.